# I added a line to the cmd.txt file to clear password. Now, i cannot set a password

Tags: pi-3b+

the file cmdline.txt got init=/bin/sh added to the end.
When I reboot, I do not need a password.
but It will not allow me to create one either.
do I need to now remove the added instruction? in order to create a new password? It goes through the new password create, but fails, and will not save it.

Comment: What are you hoping to do by adding this command? Are you trying to reset the Pi or another users password? Or is there something else you want to do?

Comment: Your headline is "*I added a line to the cmd.txt file* ...". Did you mean **cmdline.txt**? If so then you cannot add a line to it. It **must** have only one line otherwise it will break your bootup.

Answer (score 2):

From the title of your question I'm guessing you are following some instructions form somewhere telling you to add `init=/bin/sh` to `cmdline.txt` in order to boot your Pi in "single user mode". What you are doing here is interrupting the normal boot process after the bare minimum required and running a shell as the `root` user -- the result being you are logged in without a password.

The instructions then probably tell you to use the `passwd pi` command to re-set the forgotten password for the user `pi`? However, because the Pi hasn't completed the usual boot process the filesystem hasn't been mounted fully yet and is still "read-only". The result being that the `passwd pi` command can't save the new password to the filesystem so has no effect when your reboot.

The solution is to (re-)mount the SD card "read-write" first, before you run your `passwd pi` command. Do this with the `mount -n -o remount,rw /` command followed by the `passwd pi` command. Finally, remove the `init=/bin/sh` from `cmdline.txt` and reboot.

Comment: Before reboot, you could also fix up `cmdline.txt`

Comment: Good point, I'll amend my answer.